# linker error undefined reference calling PsGetProcess

Tags: c++, c, drivers, rootkit

this is a code that hides a specific process given the Pid, but i can not get PsGetCurrentProcess() working, it keeps throwing undefined reference error and i dont know what to do here is the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include "ddk\ntddk.h"
#include <stdio.h>
unsigned long SearchProcId(unsigned int Pid){

unsigned long eproc,aux,proceso,ret;
PLIST_ENTRY lista;
unsigned int idProceso=0;

eproc=(unsigned long)PsGetCurrentProcess();//estamos en "System"
lista=(LIST_ENTRY*)(eproc+0x88);//tenemos los punteros al siguiente y al anterior
aux=(unsigned long)lista->Blink;
proceso=(unsigned long)lista;
idProceso=*((int *)(proceso+0x84));

while(proceso!=0 && aux!=proceso && Pid!=idProceso)//recorremos la lista
{
    proceso-=0x88;
    ret=proceso;

    idProceso=*((int *)(proceso+0x84));
    //avanzamos
    lista=lista->Flink;
    proceso=(unsigned long)lista;
}

if(Pid!=idProceso)
ret=0;

return ret;
}








int main(int argc, char** argv) {
PLIST_ENTRY plist_active_procs;
unsigned long eproc=0;
printf ("id del proceso del lol?");
unsigned int i=0;
scanf ("%d",&i);
eproc = SearchProcId(i);
plist_active_procs = (LIST_ENTRY*)(eproc+0x88);
plist_active_procs -> Blink -> Flink=plist_active_procs->Flink;
plist_active_procs -> Flink -> Blink=plist_active_procs->Blink;

return 0;
}
```

it keeps throwing me this error i don't know what to do C:\Users\Gabriel\Documents\main.o   main.cpp:(.text+0xe): undefined reference to `*imp*_IoGetCurrentProcess@0'

Comment: Can we get your compiler command and output...  Also, your two closing } are missing 4 spaces.

Comment: If you check a [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff559933%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) it will tell you what library you need to link with.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you are including `<iostream>` and `ddk/ntddk.h` in the same source file indicates that you are probably not writing a driver.

`PsGetCurrentProcess` is only available to drivers. In normal applications you should use [`GetCurrentProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683179%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Of course, going poking around the process control blocks, like the other parts of your code does, won't work at all in user-mode. If you want to do that, you need to build a driver (and thus, remove all stdio, iostream and similar usage - you need to write a separate application that feeds the data into and out of the driver)

Comment: Short answer, you can't. Maybe you can explain what you are ACTUALLY trying to do (looks like you are trying to hide your own process, which is a naughty thing to do - not sure I want to help you do that).

Comment: yep that it is a program that hides a process given the Pid